# prove that every lossless compression algorithm must result in increasing the file size for some inputs.?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Using Pigeonhole Principle prove that every lossless compression algorithm must result in increasing the file size for some inputs.?

Comment: Not every one. If the algorithm does absolutely nothing, the file size will not increase.

Comment: Maybe it's true if we change it to weakly increasing though.

Comment: True, but you'd need at least 1 bit flag to tell it should do nothing.

Comment: Consider an alphabet with 256 charecters we can compress it if we assign a shorter bit pattern to letters that are used more frequently in the original file but this means that some charecters need longer bit patterns.  If every charecter is used the same number of times then there is no advantage in compressing the file but you still need to flag somehow that the file is uncompressed making the file slightly larger though it may only be by one byte.

Comment: The algorithm need not nontrivially compress anything though. It could simply do nothing, then the file size wouldn't increase even by one byte.

Comment: This is actually a brilliant question. Anyone who downvotes it is a brain-dead f*cking jerk!

Comment: Related - here is an example of a file system that stores the file as a location in PI https://github.com/philipl/pifs

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have an input file with $N$ bits.

You'd have $2^N$ possible inputs.

Suppose you could compress this for all inputs to $K$ bits, with $K < N$, these can only form $2^K$ compressions.

This would be the equivalent of pigeon hole principle with $2^N$ items and $2^K$ containers. Since $2^N > 2^K$, we would have at least two items in one container.

But then decompressing at least one item would yield two results, making the the compression either irreversible or not lossless.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose not. That is, suppose that we had a lossless
compression algorithm A that makes some files smaller and does
not make any files larger.

Let x be the shortest file whose compressed size is smaller than
its original size. (If there are two such files of the same length,
pick either at random.) Suppose that the input size of x is m
characters.

Suppose that S is the set of distinct files with fewer than m
characters. Because x shrinks, A compresses x to a file in S.
Because no files smaller than x shrink, each file in S compresses
to a file (perhaps the same, perhaps different) in S.

Now we have a problem. A is supposed to be lossless, therefore
one-to-one. But A maps a set containing at least |S| + 1 files to
a set containing |S| files, so the Pigeonhole Principle states that
two input files must be mapped to the same output file. This is
a contradiction.