# Why does the pigegonhole principle tell us that PI-indexing is not possible?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pigeonhole-principle

There has been a discussion about [PI-Indexing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853654/what-is-the-term-for-pi-indexing) and [irrational number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) here.

Now suppose you want to use indexes of [PI to store information](https://github.com/philipl/pifs) (file storage). To get around the fact that the indexes will be bigger than the files you're storing, you use tree of indexes - PI at a certain value is a pointer to PI at a another value.

Here the author [writes](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8019189):

> By the pigeonhole principle, no matter how fast you can calculate pi, you cannot actually use this to compress data. The index to relevant sequence is on average >= the size of the data to be stored.

Now I'm looking at the [pigeonhole principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) - and I'm not connecting to why it says this is not possible. (It sounds plausible).

My question is: **Why does the pigegonhole principle tell us that PI-indexing is not possible?**

---

EDIT: A related example - here is an [example of a filesystem](https://github.com/philipl/pifs) that stores files as locations in PI.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163457/prove-that-every-lossless-compression-algorithm-must-result-in-increasing-the-fi.

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in the first sentence of the Wikipedia entry:

*The pigeonhole principle states that if $n$ items are put into $m$ containers, with $n>m$, then at least one container must contain more than one item*.

So while you might be able to compress data using a clever PI-indexing algorithm, you will not be able to de-compress it to the original data, as one piece of compressed data might correspond to more than one de-compressed piece of data.

Comment: Thank you  @Klangen. The Wikipedia entry doesn’t tell me anything about the compression method. You explanation seems to suggest that an optimisation might be used for duplicate pieces of data. I don’t see why duplicate data would hold up decompression. Your answer then suggests I might use a one-way decompression method, I’m not sure why I’d do that.

Comment: @hawkeye Perhaps this post (on CS.Stackexchange) will interest you: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44594/data-compression-using-prime-numbers It explains the same principle, but in another context